# VB.net anonymous type has incorrect property casing from AJAX call

Tags: ajax, json, vb.net

We have noticed that sometimes from the results of an AJAX call to a controller action that the case of the JSON result is incorrect. The returned case will actually change if we rebuild our solution and try the exact same call. In the following case, the key's case has been correct for over a year until now when it has decided to start randomly changing depending on some seemingly random circumstances.

[image: Casing issue]

As you can see in the picture above, the key for the JSON result is lowercase "success". However when I view the results in Chrome's console, it is an uppercase "Success". This is causing our JavaScript to fail since it is checking for the lowercase version.

What is causing this? And more importantly, how do we stop this?

Comment: Do you have any anonymous types anywhere with `.Success` instead of `.success`?

Comment: Anywhere? Yes, only because we have run into this issue in the past and we attempted to fix it with that. But even then, it will change the case of the key. Also that is in another file completely.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the compiler is optimising them to be the same anonymous type, and whichever get compiled first "wins" (I've seen this in the past where the namespace was mis-cased in a VB project, and it meant the built namespace was indeterminate, which came to light when a C# client library came along)

Comment: Yeah we have find some article somewhere that says that this is specific to VB and it will not happen in C#, but we have never found concrete evidence for this. Unfortunately our main project is in VB, but the rest of the solution is in C#.

Comment: Have you considered reflecting the compiled code to see if the two instances are compiled as the same type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vb.net` is *case-insensitive* as opposed to `C#` which is *case-sensitive*. This means that the compiler will generate only *one* class (from the first instance) for each of the following anonymous types:

```
Dim a = New With {.success = True} 'Compiler generate a class based on this type
Dim b = New With {.Success = True} 'Same type as `a`
Dim c = New With {.sUcCeSs = True} 'Same type as `a`

Debug.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name)
Debug.WriteLine(b.GetType().Name)
Debug.WriteLine(c.GetType().Name)
```

> VB$AnonymousType_0'1
>   VB$AnonymousType_0'1
>   VB$AnonymousType_0'1

Here's how the complied code looks like when compiled back to vb.net:

```
<DebuggerDisplay("success={success}"), CompilerGenerated> _
Friend NotInheritable Class VB$AnonymousType_0(Of T0)
    ' Methods
    <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
    Public Sub New(ByVal success As T0)
        Me.$success = success
    End Sub

    <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim builder As New StringBuilder
        builder.Append("{ ")
        builder.AppendFormat("{0} = {1} ", "success", Me.$success)
        builder.Append("}")
        Return builder.ToString
    End Function

    Public Property success As T0
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Get
            Return Me.$success
        End Get
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Set(ByVal Value As T0)
            Me.$success = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private $success As T0

End Class
```

Comment: Fascinating! Do you know of a means to force the compiler to consistently select one interpretation every time?

Comment: AFAIK there's no "cure". Either ensure proper casing or switch to C# ;)

Comment: Unfortunately a pretty good chunk of our business logic is wrapped up in this VB behemoth. In the meantime we're going to ditch the anonymous types and use a proper class for this. C# migration is on the to-do list :)